# Converting PHP array into item object to use with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays, json

I have bunch of for loops in php which feed folder names and file locations to a 6 dimensional array. Here is the code behind the loops: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/66aa7cabe47f91eda6835e193d04a92d

I have a single page application which displays information based on these folder names/ array size. These are the folder levels I need to traverse through:

- Environment (of which there are 4)
- Feature name (of which is an undefined value)
- Day (date - of which is an undefined value)
- Time (timestamp - of which is an undefined value)
- Report Link (file location of an html file on the server ^ based on above folder structure - of which is an undefined value)
- .json file location on the server ^ based on the above folder structure - of which is an undefined value

I have written some php code which `json_encode`s the `$folderStructure` array and then `json_decode`s it to a nice readable format:

```
<?php

    require('data.php');

    $data = json_encode($folderStructure); // decode the JSON into an associative array

    $changed = json_decode($data, true);

    echo '<pre>' . print_r($changed, true) . '</pre>'; // This will print out the contents of the array in a nice readable format

?>
```

And the output is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/944e97b98596454a27cc8236a4420dbd

As you can see, there is a lot of data. As the size of the array will increase, the loading of the data will take longer. I have been suggested to use AngularJS to display the page contents (as opposed to what I have currently -  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/429747625b113df0bed30c727a338ffe (which is very very inneficient). Dicionaries are apparently a lot faster to traverse and thus the sensible solution is to convert this single page application to be written in AngularJS.

I have experiemented with the below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="controllerName">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(environment, number) in items">{{environment}}: {{number}}</li>
    </ul>

</div>

    <script>
        angular.module('app', [])
            .controller('controllerName', function($scope)
            {
                $scope.items = {'DEV':10, 
                                'Production':12
                                ,'Staging':10
                                ,'QA':12

                                };
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And wondered whether it would be possible for me to convert my PHP array into one of these `items` objects and use `ng-repeat` to display the information rather than PHP. Is this something than can be achieved? I'm a bit stumped as to how to achieve this, would anyone be able to help me out with this?

EDIT: My current PHP solution works but is however slow as it relies on arrays.
What I wanted to achieve is something that looks similar to this: [image] except to be written in AngularJS (using a `ng-repeat` from a dictionary) instead of for loops in PHP.

So to put it in black and white, based on my current design: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/429747625b113df0bed30c727a338ffe - how can I convert the `$folderStructure` array into some sort of object or dictionary and use that to display information on the page using ng-repeat?

EDIT 2: `Why would json_encode not work? JSON is Javascript Object Notation.`
Well, okay. How do I pass in the value of the array into: `$scope.items` and create a name value pair without hardcoding the values myself? 1) I don't know the folder names after the initial `environment` array position of `$folderStructure` as they change all the time. 2) I don't know how big the array will be in the future either.

EDIT 3:

I've altered some code in index.php to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

            <p>{{myStuff}}</p>

        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

            // get the data using a http request
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) 
            {
                $http.get("php/get_data.php").then(function (response) 
                {
                    $scope.myStuff = response.data;
                });
            });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem is, the output for `myStuff` is literally this: pastebin.com/CyiZ5UhG

Is there a way for me to iterate through this ouput and use ng-repeat for each of the headers (without me knowing what the headers are)?

Comment: Why would json_encode not work?  JSON is Javascript Object Notation..

Comment: Alight @Devon , but would you be able to explain to me how I would be able to traverse through the json in order to have an ng-repeat for each array position? ie ideal output: 4*EnvironmentName, x* featureName, x* dayName etc?

Comment: could you provide the result of  <<< json_encode($folderStructure); >>> to improve my answer

Comment: @swordf1zh Hi, thanks for the reply. Please see this: http://pastebin.com/CyiZ5UhG - result of `echo json_encode($folderStructure);`

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `ngRepeat` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-repeat="itemChild_level1 in item">
    <div ng-repeat="itemChild_level2 in itemChild_level1>
      ...
      <p>{{ itemChild_levelX.property</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you be able to improve on your solution based on EDIT 3 of my question please? As your solution only covers a slight portion of what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i´m going to try to keep it short;

I think that your problem is how to inject the json, and the easiest for you would be to inject it this way:

```
    <script>
        angular.module('app', [])
            .controller('controllerName', function($scope, $datasources){
                $scope.items = $datasources["dataset1"];
            }).value("$datasources", {
               dataset1:<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>,
            });
    </script>
```

However, I would suggest you further reading about angular services. What I would do instead of this, is to create a service that retrieves that data through $http directive, and call it inside the controller declaration like this:

```
            .factory("DataService", function($http, $q){
                return{
                    get:function(){
                       var deferred = $q.defer();

                       $http.get("urlWithData").then(function(data){
                          deferred.resolve(data)
                       }, function(error){
                          deferred.reject(error);
                       })
                       return deferred.promise;
                    }
            })
            ....
            .controller('controllerName', function($scope, DataService){
                DataService.get().then(function(data){
                     $scope.items = data;
                });
            })
```

**EDIT:**

The html code to iterate through your records (use it as a hint, honestly, not going to study the structure of that code in pastebin ^^):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

            <ul>
                 <li ng-repeat = "(index, item) in myStuff">
                      <ul ng-if = 'typeof item == 'Array'">
                          <li ng-repeat = "(subindex, subitem) in item"></li>                        
                          etc ...
                      </ul>
                      <p ng-if= "typeof item == 'String'">{{item}}</p>
                 </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

            // get the data using a http request
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) 
            {
                $http.get("php/get_data.php").then(function (response) 
                {
                    $scope.myStuff = response.data;
                });
            });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

BTW, why such a deep nesting in your data?? seems needlessly complicated

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you be able to improve on your solution based on `EDIT 3` of my question please? As your solution only covers a slight portion of what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: I will try... but not sure about the problem you have with it. I´ll assume that when you say "literally" you mean the content of the refered link, and not the text itself :)